# Memory profiler software - How to use them? Examples?

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, memory-profiling

If I want to check a program for memory leaks, what method should I use to go about this?
What software is available and how do you use that software? I'd like to see if there is a memory leak occuring in some code I have here and I'm not really sure how to check it.

Thanks!

Comment: You might get better answers if you specified what platform you're using. Memory profiling for apps running native code is a bit different than memory profiling for stuff running on the JVM, for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the language you're trying to profile.

There are C profilers that will replace the default memory allocators with instrumented ones, and probably a number of newer, better techniques - it's been a long time since I've used them.  Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818673/memory-profiler-for-c).

For .Net, [Red Gate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_memory_profiler/index.htm) makes a good profiler - I've used it, and it's well worth it.

I'm not sure what's available for java - a quick search indicates there are a couple of open source profilers.

I'm also not sure what's available for javascript, though I'm sure they exist.

Comment: For .NET, Red Gate is awesome. An alternative is dotTrace from JetBrains.